# Is there a positive verb "to not do anything about"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a positive verb meaning "to do something about," we have "address" or "handle."

For a negative verb meaning leave alone or not do anything about or not give attention to, we have "neglect."  Also "disregard" is a more neutral word, but it specifically means to not pay attention to rather than to omit *action* concerning.

Is there a verb without negative connotation that means "to omit action or activity concerning; to not do anything about"?

Example sentence:

> I am going to _____ this project, as I think the people running it are doing just fine on their own.

---

Edit: Since a couple people in the comments somehow think such a verb is intrinsically impossible—an interesting concept—I'll mention several other words that are similar in many ways and do not have any inherent negative connotation, at least demonstrating that it's not fundamentally impossible to have a word with the meaning I've described above, even if there isn't a well known word that does:

Words/idioms with similar meanings and without negative connotations include: abstain, refrain, leave alone, let be, hold off (on something), tolerate, live with.

Comment: In order to 'omit action' one, of necessity, makes it impossible for a verb to describe that non-existent action.

Comment: @NigelJ, the word "omit" is a verb.  And the word "indescribable" is an adjective.  It's extremely odd that you say a description would be *necessarily* impossible; that's just not true.

Comment: The question rules out any active verb and what is described is not entirely passive because observation is involved. But let us wait and see what verbs are offered . . . . .

Comment: @NigelJ, again that's a peculiar thing to say.  Active and passive are *grammatical modes* in which *any* verb can be used, regardless of the *meaning* of the verb.  (Actually I don't think you can use an intransitive verb in passive mode, but the point stands.)  "He lazed around the house" uses the active mode.  "He was rushed through the line" uses the passive mode.  But I agree we'll wait and see what answers come in.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that an intransitive verb cannot be transformed into a passive - which is the problem. I have up-voted the question in order to attract attention and to see what will become of it.

Comment: I can only think of words like 'ignore', which I assume you would consider to have negative connotations. To express your meaning I think you have to say something like "I am not going to interfere with this project..."

Comment: How could there be a verb without negative connotation meaning anything like *not do anything about*, please?

How could the most positive verb meaning anything like *not do anything about* not have *negative connotations*?

Comment: _Skip_ could work. _OED_ definition: "To pass over without mentioning, dealing with, taking into account, etc.; to omit."

Comment: How about *ignore*?

Comment: From the political scene, we have such options as _study_, _defer_, _table_, and _send to committee_.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'abeyance' is what you need.  eg 'The project was put in abeyance' meaning it was suspended or held over without necessarily meaning for any negative reason.  You could also say something had its priority reduced, or it was reprioritised, but this is a little negative.

Comment: Thanks; that's a good non-negative word, but tends to imply that *no one* is doing anything on the project, rather than specifically that the speaker only is not personally doing anything to it or with it, leaving others to do or not do whatever they may.  See my example sentence again.

Comment: OK, if it just one person not doing anything, what about saying 'Fred has stood aside from the project' or 'Fred has taken a side role'?

Answer (score 1):

The positive alternative to the concept of neglecting or ignoring something is to *set it free* or to *release* it. It has 'graduated' beyond the need for your involvement. However, *release* already has a different definition in the jargon of project management, and *set free* is perhaps overenthusiastic in the corporate space.

Consider *cut loose*:

> **cut loose**
>   1 : to free from control or restraint
>   *cut us loose from the contract*
>   [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut%20loose)

Your example sentence would then be:

- I am going to *cut* this project *loose* as I think the people running it are doing just fine on their own.

If you don't mind the verb referring to yourself, you could *retire*:

- I am going to *retire from* this project, as I think the people running it are doing just fine on their own.

> **retire** *transitive verb*
>   1c : to withdraw from usual use or service
>   [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retire)

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is 'bypass.'  That refers to avoiding something, not for dislike, and without criticism for doing so.  When you bypass a road, there is no judgment, unlike disdain, abjure, or avoid.